# Translate SQL query into a well made QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a raw queryset that i want to translate in QuerySet. But i always ends up with error.

Here is the raw query :

```
q = Table1.objects.raw(
     '''SELECT base_table1.id, base_table1.name, base_table1.n_id, count(base_table2.id) as 'count', max(base_table2.timestamp) as 'latest'
                                     FROM base_table1
                                     INNER JOIN base_table3 on base_table3.table1_id = base_table1.id
                                     INNER JOIN base_table2 on base_table2.table3_id = base_table3.id
                                     GROUP by base_table1.id'''
```

Note : here i don't need the base_table1.id, but it was required for the rawQuerySet

Here are the models :

```
class Table1(models.Model):
n_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Table2(models.Model):
table3 = models.ForeignKey(
    Table3, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


class Table3(models.Model):
table1 = models.ForeignKey(
    Table1, null=True, related_name='t_entries', on_delete=models.SET_NULL
)
```

Great thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: I edited the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `Table1` model with:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Count

Table1.objects.annotate(
    count=Count('t_entries__table3'),
    latest=Max('t_entries__table3__timestamp')
)
```

The `Table1` objects that arise from this queryset will have extra attributes `.count` and `.latest`.